# Combining jQuery draggable, droppable, and sortable

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-droppable

I'm trying to combine jQuery draggable, droppable, and sortable; however, I keep having problems. Can anybody help me?

Basically, the idea is illustrated here: 
[image]

- A, B, C, D, E tiles can be moved between the upper droppable and the sortable.
- The custom (*) tile can be moved only between the left-side droppable and the sortable.

*Also, I'm trying to be able to deactivate and reactivate all these at any standing when necessary.*

---

This is what I have, but it's very buggy and not pretty:

**JS**

```
var gameContainer = $(".game");

var myTray = $(".tray").sortable({
    containment: gameContainer,
    helper: "clone",
    revert: 100,
    tolerance: "pointer",
    update: function(ev, ui) {
        ui.item.addClass("ontray").css({
            "left": "0px",
            "position": "static",
            "top": "0px"
        });
    }
}).disableSelection();

var setTileDraggable = function(tileSelector) {
    tileSelector.draggable({
        connectToSortable: myTray,
        containment: gameContainer,
        helper: "original",
        revert: "invalid"
    }).disableSelection();
};

var myBoard = $(".board").droppable({
    accept: ".tile:not(.red)",
    drop: function(ev, ui) {
        if (ui.draggable.hasClass("ontray")) {
            // tile (not red) coming from tray, place it into .tiles child div
            var cloneTile = ui.draggable.clone().removeClass("ontray").show();
            myBoard.children(".tiles").append(cloneTile);
            var dropx = ui.offset.left - myBoard.offset().left;
            var dropy = ui.offset.top - myBoard.offset().top;
            cloneTile.css({
                "left": dropx + "px",
                "position": "absolute",
                "top": dropy + "px"
            });
            setTileDraggable(cloneTile);
            ui.helper.remove();
            ui.draggable.remove();
        }
    }
}).disableSelection();

var myCustomTile = $(".custom").droppable({
    accept: ".tile.red",
    drop: function(ev, ui) {
        if (ui.draggable.hasClass("ontray")) {
            // red tile coming from tray
            var cloneTile = ui.draggable.clone().removeClass("ontray").show();
            myCustomTile.append(cloneTile);
            setTileDraggable(cloneTile);
            setTileClick(cloneTile);
            ui.helper.remove();
            ui.draggable.remove();
        } else {
            // red tile staying, move back to original position
            ui.draggable.stop(true, false).animate({
                "left": "0px",
                "top": "0px"
            });
        }
    }
}).disableSelection();

// set up draggables
setTileDraggable(myBoard.children(".tiles").find(".tile"));
setTileDraggable(myCustomTile.find(".tile"));
```

HTML

```
<div class="game">
    <div class="board">
        <div class="tiles">
            <div class="tile">D</div>
            <div class="tile">B</div>
            <div class="tile">E</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="custom">
        <div class="tile red">X</div>
    </div>
    <div class="tray">
        <div class="tile">C</div>
        <div class="tile">A</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I was able to figure it out: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jxDCt
This actually works well.

Comment: This definetly helped me, but there is a bug that makes the tiles from the tray being duplicated, most probably because of the helper. (I know this is old, but this might of use to someone, just like me)

Answer (score 6):

It's a much easier project if you make all your boxes sortables, since they have existing methods to connect with each other easily. Here's a quick implementation of your example:

[Live Demo](http://codepen.io/neagle/pen/fuIqs)

```
$('.alpha').sortable({
  connectWith: '.gamma',
  receive: function (event, ui) {
    if ($(ui.item).hasClass('special')) {
      ui.sender.sortable('cancel');
    }
  }
});

$('.beta').sortable({
  connectWith: '.gamma',
  receive: function (event, ui) {
    if (!$(ui.item).hasClass('special')) {
      ui.sender.sortable('cancel');
    }
  }
});

$('.gamma').sortable({
  appendTo: document.body,
  items: '.tile',
  connectWith: '.alpha, .beta',
  receive: function (event, ui) {
    //console.log(event, ui.item);
    //ui.item.remove(); // remove original item
  }
});
```

You can see that it's mainly

- Setting up sortables, and
- Creating custom receive events that accept or reject specific kinds of tiles, based on your specifications

Comment: Thanks, but I need to keep the tiles positioned absolutely in ".alpha" because they are supposed to stay wherever you drop them. Any way I could do that?