# Jquery : Draggable items linked between SortableList and DroppableArea clone issue

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, draggable, jquery-ui-sortable, jquery-ui-draggable

I'm working on a panel made of 2 parts :

- A list : containing all my widgets, and I'd like every widget to be draggable and sortable.
- An area : containing an image where I want to drop my widgets on (and save their position later on) : So I need my widgets to be droppable and draggable.

I'm trying to do that behavior with JQuery UI. On top of that, I'd like to be able to drag my widgets from the list to the area, and if I want, drag them back to the list.

---

**EDIT :**  https://jsfiddle.net/Tenmak/jzmsatrg/ (new link)

```
var myImageSlot = $("#image_slot").droppable({
    accept: ".listItem",
    drop: function(ev, ui) {
      console.log('dropped');

      if (ui.draggable.hasClass("ontray")) {
        var cloneTile = ui.draggable.clone()
            .removeClass("ontray")
          .removeClass("ui-sortable-handle")
          .show();
        myImageSlot.children(".itemsContainer").append(cloneTile);
        var dropx = ui.offset.left - myImageSlot.offset().left;
        var dropy = ui.offset.top - myImageSlot.offset().top;

        cloneTile.css({
          "left": dropx + "px",
          "position": "absolute",
          "top": dropy + "px"
        });
        setTileDraggable(cloneTile);
        ui.helper.remove();
        ui.draggable.remove();
      }
    }
  }).disableSelection();
```

By setting absolute position to the draggable item when outside of the list, the wanted behavior is there, and the animation is smoother, but sometimes, it gets duplicated most probably because of the clone() method not working correctly.

Is there any way to correct this buggy behavior ? Should I proceed differently ? 
Any help would be really nice, I feel I'm getting there but some tips or anythins would really be helful.
N.B : I'm opening a bounty as soon as I can because I really need this.

Comment: This seems pretty much close to it, I'm gonna look into it : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20385177/combining-jquery-draggable-droppable-and-sortable?rq=1

Comment: Your problem seems to be the same as in this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12549841/jquery-ui-draggable-connecttosortable-without-helper-clone-or-how-to-move-it. The solution would be to set `helper: 'clone'` for the draggable component, as specified in the [jQuery UI documentation](https://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#option-connectToSortable). You will have to manage the duplication of the dragged element according to that change. The first answer of the SO post may help you with that.

Comment: Can you check my answer below?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope I have fixed the issue you had with the duplicates when doing the clone after the drop.

The reason I found is, its getting cloned twice when you quickly drag and drop items between the containers since the drop event called twice for some reason as the fastest movements would have triggered it.

To fix this, I setup an index to each draggable item on the load with help of data attribute and checking the same when appending the item to the container for any of the same index exists already to avoid the duplication.

Then I tested this a lot and can't able to replicate the issue no more. So I hope it solved the issue but anyways I will need you to check and confirm :-)

Here is the updated fiddle link,

https://jsfiddle.net/balasuar/jzmsatrg/4/

The fix I did is,

A method to setup index

```
var setupItemIndex = function(index) {
     return function(container) {
        container.find(".listItem").each(function(){
                    $(this).attr('data-index', index++);
        });
     };
  }(0);
```

Then initiating the index setup for both containers,

```
setupItemIndex($('#listContainer'));
setupItemIndex($('#image_slot'));
```

Then retrieving the index of the dropped item,

```
  var targetContainer = myImageSlot.children(".itemsContainer");
  var itemIndex = ui.draggable.attr('data-index');
```

Then, checking this index whether exists already in the right container before appending it there.

```
if(targetContainer.has('[data-index="' + itemIndex + '"]').length === 0) {
        myImageSlot.children(".itemsContainer").append(cloneTile);

        -----

}
```

Give a go :-)

Comment: Nice, in the end it seems to be more of a hack than a correct behavior, but hey it's working. Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

I had to start from scratch and ended up with and heavily modified code. Hope it helps.

**working fiddle**

https://jsfiddle.net/ergec/thj7sz0w/

**html**

```
<div class="master" id="master_containment">
    <div class="container sortables" id="listContainer">
        <div class="listItem">Item 1</div>
        <div class="listItem">Item 2</div>
        <div class="listItem">Item 3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="container" id="image_slot">
        <div class="itemsContainer sortables">
            <div class="listItem">Item 4</div>
            <div class="listItem">Item 5</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**css**

```
.sortable-placeholder {
    height: 60px;
    width: 60px;
    background-color: yellow;
    float: left;
}

.listItem {
    background: #00e;
    color: #fff;
    height: 60px;
    line-height: 60px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 60px;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 999;
}

.container {
    background: teal;
    border 1px;
    border-style: solid;
    width: 250px;
    height: 200px;
    padding: 10px;
}

#image_slot {
    background: brown;
    position: absolute;
    left: 300px;
    top: 8px;
}

.master {
    width: 560px;
    height: 220px;
}

.itemsContainer {
    height: 200px;
}
```

**js**

```
$("#listContainer").sortable({
    placeholder: "sortable-placeholder",
    containment: "#master_containment",
    connectWith: ".itemsContainer",
    revert: 100
}).find(".listitem").draggable({
    connectToSortable: ".sortables",
    containment: "#master_containment",
    helper: "original",
    revert: "invalid"
}).disableSelection();
$(".itemsContainer").sortable({
    placeholder: "sortable-placeholder",
    containment: "#master_containment",
    connectWith: "#listContainer",
    revert: 100
}).find(".listItem").draggable({
    connectToSortable: ".sortables",
    containment: "#master_containment",
    helper: "original",
    revert: "invalid"
}).disableSelection();
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but the behavior in my JSfiddle is actually the correct one, I want the right side to be an area where I can place my items where I want, and not have a list like the left area.
I just want my fiddle not to duplicate items like it does sometimes.
(If you take item 5 to the left, and then back to the right one, sometimes it's buggy)

Comment: Ah I thought list on the left is the target,  my bad. Yes droppable has been buggy for several years,  6 may be 7. Drop event triggers even if there is no actual drop. You may get a workaround but I wonder if it's a good idea to rely on it. It may cause more trouble in the later stages of the code. I'll see what I can do. Hope you find your answer.